# Crossfading 2 images with 0.7 opacity

Tags: css, image, opacity, cross-fade

I have two pictures on top of each other, where if you hover over the top, it will fade from `opacity:1` to `opacity:0` after 1s.

I want them to have `opacity:0.7` as default, and then, when hovered over the other one should be shown.

The problem I am having is that both images are shown with `opacity:0.7` right now, because, obviously, they are slightly transparent.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you give us some code... or even a working example

Comment: It will be easier to see what you mean with a code example

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand is that your underlying image is a little bit visible too.

What you need to do is to set the opacity of the first image to 0, like so:

```css
.img-overlay {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.img-overlay img {
  opacity: .7;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.img-overlay img:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Set opacity to 0, ... */
.img-overlay:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* ... but only for the last image set it to .7 */
.img-overlay:hover img:last-child {
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="img-overlay">
  <img src="http://pipsum.com/235x110.jpg?1" />
  <img src="http://pipsum.com/235x110.jpg?2" />
</a>
```